# Computer Puzzle - What OS am I?

Tags: riddle

What computer OS am I?

> I saw the rise, watched the fall.
>
> Killed the poor, nigh the rich.
>
> Released for you, meant for none.
>
> I remember, those are none.

Comment: Wait, there are more than 1 IOS?

Comment: nah he means "OS" as in operating system. not the apple one

Comment: @North Well, in addition to Apple's iOS, there's also a Cisco IOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I guess that the answer is(Read the whole answer for complete explanation):

> Android OS.

I saw the rise, watched the fall.

> when the android market rose, it rose tremendously and with that it marked or saw the fall of many previous mobile systems including java based mobiles or nokia's Symbian OS which was very popular, Microsoft Windows based Mobile OS , blackberry OS etc., which saw a drastic fall in terms of sales in comparison to android OS based smart phones when they came into trend back in 2011 when gingerbread was launched officially.

Killed the poor, nigh the rich.

> I guess this is related in terms of money i.e. earlier android based smart phones cost a bomb and it killed the pockets of poor people as not everyone could afford the same back in those days. It was the affair for the rich people who can one and it was near to them.

Released for you, meant for none.

> The early intentions of the android developers were to develop an advanced operating system for digital cameras, but they sooner realized that a smartphone market could target a bigger market so it was therefore pitched in as a phone based OS. So in that context it can be said that it was later released for everyone but company's plan were different earlier.

I remember, those are none.

> For this it can be said that later android OS not only targeted the mobile phones but also cameras, TV's, tablets with their OS. (none but many).

P.S.

> Android OS is largely based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software. Linux as we know is popular computer OS. Moreover a number of emulators are available in market including bluestacks, bliss etc using which we can run android OS on computer as well. Plus this is somewhat misleading since we are comparing computing per se with smartphones and have to ask ourselves if these smartphones are indeed computers. They just so happen to be used for telecommunications, but the desktop computer is also used for telecommunications. The main difference is that one is portable and the other is not. Another difference is power. The handheld smartphone is a gutless wonder compared with the desktop machine, but it can run a browser, some apps, and interactive maps. For more info consider reading this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_computer#Modern_use

So,

> In this light a smartphone can be termed as a "PORTABLE COMPUTER" as stated by wikipedia and "ANDROID" can be termed as a valid answer.

Comment: The riddle says 'what COMPUTER OS am I?', so I guess this exclude mobile OS. But i might be wrong

Comment: Updated my answer @Nank

Comment: This is the correct answer, the android os is like a mini computer, aswell as it is based off of a linux kernel. I did not think anyone would catch this.

Comment: @Colea I got the answer as soon as I read the first line.

Comment: Well, good job!

Answer (score 2):

You are

> [MS DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS)

I saw the rise, watched the fall.

> It was *the* dominant OS for PC-compatibles, way into the time when other OS'es were much more advanced, mostly thanks to a combination of inertia, market dominance and business practice. But eventually it was sidelined by MS Windows, when Windows finally became more or less usable.

Killed the poor, nigh the rich.

> At the time IBM PC has been introduced, it was widely expected that [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) spin-off would be the OS of choice. While Digital Research was not an unsuccessful company, an incident where [Gary Kindall missed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall#IBM_dealings) the deal with IBM caused IBM to turn to Bill Gates instead - and the rest is history,making Bill Gates the richest person in the world. While CP/M went into obsolescence and Digital Research dwindled and eventually has been sold to Novell.

Released for you, meant for none.

> [FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS) is an OpenSource MS-DOS compatible OS, released, as the OpenSource goes, for the benefit of us, the users. However, the original, Microsoft MS-DOS would never ever be released as an OpenSource, certainly not while there is a possibility of earning money out of it.

I remember, those are none.

> Users did not ever mean much for Microsoft. Profits did :-)